# Compile time errors with dagger

Tags: android, dagger-2

Very often while compiling I get the following error:

> Error:(5, 18) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerDataComponent
>   Error:(14, 21) error: cannot find symbol class DaggerNetComponent
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

It is enough to start building again with no changes to make the building succeeding.

I have the Instant Run feature disabled.
I'm using Java8 with retrolambda and dagger2 2.8.

This is my build.gradle:

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
        }
    }

    plugins {
        id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.3.1"
    }

    // Required because retrolambda is on maven central
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'realm-android'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
        compileOptions.incremental = false

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.app"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
            jackOptions {
                enabled false
            }
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            dexOptions {
                preDexLibraries = false
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }

        }

        compileOptions {
            incremental true
        }

        /**
         * Signing keys config.
         */
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file("ddebug.keystore")
                keyAlias "ddebug"
                storePassword "07477800086d!"
                keyPassword "07477800086d!"
            }
            release {
                storeFile file("drelease.keystore")
                keyAlias "drelease"
                storePassword "07477800086d!"
                keyPassword "07477800086d!"
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled true
                zipAlignEnabled true
                renderscriptDebuggable false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            debug {
                debuggable true
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                minifyEnabled false
                versionNameSuffix "_dev"
            }

        }
    }

    dependencies {
        apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
        provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

        apt 'com.gabrielittner.auto.value:auto-value-with:1.0.0'

        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        def supportVersion = '25.1.0'
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$supportVersion"
        compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportVersion"

        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'

        def retrofit2 = '2.1.0'
        def okhttp3 = '3.4.1'
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2"
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$retrofit2"
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit2"
        compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3"
        compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okhttp3"
        compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3"

        def butter_knife = '8.4.0'
        apt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butter_knife"
        compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butter_knife"

        def leak_canary = '1.4-beta2'
        debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leak_canary"
        releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leak_canary"
        testCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leak_canary"

        compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-support-v4:0.4.0'

        provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
        apt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
        compile 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel-adapter:0.2.5'
        apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.5'
        apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.3.2-rc1'

        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
        compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        //other dependencies for testing
        def hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
        testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$hamcrestVersion"
        testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$hamcrestVersion"
        testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:$hamcrestVersion"
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android.packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the latest version of Dagger i.e., 2.8?

Comment: Thank you @DavidRawson. Same problem with 2.8

Comment: Maybe you can include a list of your dependencies in your question to help diagnose the problem? The command is `gradle dependencies`.

Comment: Try using the jack annotationProcessor dependency scope instead of the apt one.

Comment: but I'm not using jack